# Convert js to function

Tags: javascript, nav

Anyone knows how should I add this js into functions.php?
I am trying to create a navigation bar fixed on top using that method.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).scroll(function () {
      //if you hard code, then use console
      //.log to determine when you want the 
      //nav bar to stick.  
      console.log($(window).scrollTop())
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 280) {
      $('#nav_bar').addClass('navbar-fixed');
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < 281) {
      $('#nav_bar').removeClass('navbar-fixed');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: `functions.php`?

Comment: Yes, I also created a back to top button by adding js script into functions. I want to use the same method for fixing nav bar to the top.

Comment: How does `functions.PHP` are connected with your javascript?

Comment: add_action( 'wp_footer', 'back_to_top_script' );
function back_to_top_script() {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                if ( $(this).scrollTop() > 400 )
                    $("#totop").fadeIn();
                else
                    $("#totop").fadeOut();
            });
 
            $("#totop").click(function () {
                $("body,html").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 800 );
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>';
}

Comment: Looks like your trying to add some JS via wordpress. See my answer for your specific question, however this is solved a better way (I've alluded to it but I'm no WP expert so someone else might be able to help better).

Answer (score 1):

PHP will only run on the server and so won't affect your page once it's arrived in the browser. This script needs to know information about how the page is currently being displayed in the browser window and PHP won't know that information.

This could go into your template inside script tags. Assuming this specific code already works for you just remember to add the code after you've added jQuery.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
        crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        //if you hard code, then use console
        //.log to determine when you want the 
        //nav bar to stick.  
        console.log($(window).scrollTop())
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > 280) {
        $('#nav_bar').addClass('navbar-fixed');
      }
      if ($(window).scrollTop() < 281) {
        $('#nav_bar').removeClass('navbar-fixed');
      }
    });
  });
<script>
```

This assumes jQuery 1 and uses the jQuery CDN https://code.jquery.com/

**Edit**

Based on your comments to your question:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'fixed_nav_bar' ); 

function fixed_nav_bar() { 
  echo '
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(window).scroll(function () {
        //if you hard code, then use console
        //.log to determine when you want the 
        //nav bar to stick.  
        console.log($(window).scrollTop())
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 280) {
          $("#nav_bar").addClass("navbar-fixed");
        }
        if ($(window).scrollTop() < 281) {
          $("#nav_bar").removeClass("navbar-fixed");
        }
      });
    });
    </script>
 '; 
}
```

Note: `$` and `jQuery` are usually equivicable, but for safety, feel free to replace the `$` for `jQuery`

However, ideally you would add this to your wordpress theme HTML (your other JS should go there too). Adding events is more useful if you want to have PHP perform some logic before printing stuff into the DOM.

Comment: You want to use HEREDOC strings for multiline string in PHP

Comment: Not really. HEREDOC is awful and there's no benefit.

Comment: TIL: multiline strings can be written that way. Thanks @DanielM